# Booleans in C language

Tags: c, boolean

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



_Bool check_domain(char *domain) {
    int str_count = 0, x = strlen(domain), y = 0;
    if (domain[x-1] == '.' || domain[0] == '.'){
        return false; //if there is a period at start or end
    }
    else{
        while (domain[y]){
            if (str_count==2){
                return false; //if 2 consecutive periods
            }
            if (domain[y] == 46 || 65<=domain[y]<=90 || 97<=domain[y]<=122){ //if character is period or alphanumeric
                if (domain[y] == '.'){
                    str_count += 1;
                }
                else{
                    str_count = 0;
                }
            }
            else{ // if character is non period non alphanumeric
                return false;
            }
            y += 1;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void){
    char domain[] = "nus@edu.sg";
    printf("%d",check_domain(domain));
}
```

EDIT:
Thank you for your responses, have a little more clarity on the subject now.
In addition to not having a period at the end or beginning, nor two consecutive periods, there should be no non-period, non-alphanumeric character inside the string.
For reasons I can't figure out, this code fails to return false for cases wherein there are non-period, non-alphanumeric characters inside the string.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You're missing at least 3 required `#include` directives: `<stdio.h>` (for `printf`), `<string.h>` (for `strlen`), and `<stdbool.h>` (for `false` and `true`). And `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. Those aren't the only errors. Always include your entire program (see [mre]) and the actual copy-and-pasted errors you get when you compile it.

Comment: You have `while (domain[x]) {}`, where `x` is the string length of `domain`. That means `domain[x]` will always be the null terminator at the end of the string, so the while loop will never run. It looks like you should be using `for (x = 0; domain[x]; x++) {}` instead of the `while` loop

Comment: Don't use meaningless names for variables. `i` is traditionally used as an index, whereas here you are using it to hold the number of periods you have found. If you use a better name like `periods_found` then the code will be much clearer. Likewise, probably use `i` where you are using `x`.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your assistance. I've implemented your recommendations, but there's still an issue. Could you tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: compile with all warnings and debug info. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) that means `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 1):

Start here

```
if (domain[y] == 46 || 65<=domain[y]<=90 || 97<=domain[y]<=122){
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

C can't handle statement like `n <= X <= m` in the way you expect.

C treats this as:

```
(65<=domain[y]) <= 90
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^
   bool         <= number
```

So first C will calculate a bool result from `65<=domain[y]` and then it will compare that bool to a number. The bool is converted to either 0 or 1 so when comparing with 90, the result is always true.

If you had checked the compiler warnings, you would have seen something like:

```
main.cpp:18:49: warning: comparison of constant '90' with boolean expression is always true [-Wbool-compare]

18 |             if (domain[y] == 46 || 65<=domain[y]<=90 || 97<=domain[y]<=122){
   |                                                 ^~
```

which tells you that something is wrong.

You need to write

```
if (domain[y] == 46 || (65<=domain[y] && domain[y]<=90) || (97<=domain[y] && domain[y]<=122)){
```

BTW:

Don't use magic numbers like 65, 90 and so on. Use the character instead. Like:

```
(65<=domain[y] && domain[y]<=90) --> ('A' <= domain[y] && domain[y] <= 'Z')
```

It makes the code much easier to understand.

Further - consider using the function `isalpha(domain[y])` for such checks.

Finally - Your text (and function name) says that that you want to check for a domain name. However, your input is more like an e-mail address.

Comment: More to the point, use `isalpha(domain[y])` to test for letters (alphabetic characters) — the `<ctype.h>` header is provided to avoid the use of numbers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agree - I just wanted to show OP that this was wrong. I've added a little comment about it.